# Show Another Website in My Pages on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, web, hyperlink, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to ask a question ..
I made a website using ReactJS, the contents of the starting page are Menus and when I click on one of the menus it will lead to a page with a Link from a website accompanied by several parameters.
Example:

[https://example.co.id/run?_pages=Stock.rptdesign&Group='+this.state.Group+'](https://example.co.id/run?_pages=Stock.rptdesign&Group=%27+this.state.Group+%27)

Now I don't know how to call a Website with a link like that on ReactJS.

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make menu items `<a>` tags and pass a constructed href to it, with `target="_blank"` if you want to open it in a new page,
or else if you are using react router you can use `history.push(url)` in the on click function of your menu item (here url will be your prepared url).

Comment: Can you provide a sample script from the explanation above ...?